# Firebase Datasnapshot values are not getting reflected in associated class object

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I am newbie in Firebase. I am trying to fetch data from firebase to object of the related class. The datasnapshot gets the value from Firebase, but the same values are not getting assigned to the object.

Below is my Firebase Structure:

[image]

Here is what getting me the problem:

```
 myRef =database.getReference();






    myRef.child("Tables").addChildEventListener(new ChildEventListener() {

        @Override
        public void onChildAdded( DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, String s) {
            Log.v("DS",dataSnapshot.getValue().toString());
            Tables values=dataSnapshot.getValue(Tables.class);

            Log.v("isAl", values.toString());


            int Capacity=values.getCapacity();
            String Customer=values.getCustomer();
            boolean IsAllocated= values.isAllocated();

            Log.v("isAl", String.valueOf(values.isAllocated())+"\t"+Customer+"\t"+Capacity);



            String key = dataSnapshot.getKey();
            oldKey=key;

            mKeys.add(key);

            Tables table=new Tables(Capacity,Customer,IsAllocated);
});
}
```

My Tables Class is as follows:

```
public class Tables {
    private int Capacity;
    private   String Customer;
    private   boolean IsAllocated;

public Tables(int capacity, String customer, boolean isAllocated) {
    Capacity = capacity;
    Customer = customer;
    IsAllocated = isAllocated;
}

public Tables() {
}

public int getCapacity() {
    return Capacity;
}

public void setCapacity(int capacity) {
    Capacity = capacity;
}

public String getCustomer() {
    return Customer;
}

public void setCustomer(String customer) {
    Customer = customer;
}

public boolean isAllocated() {
    return IsAllocated;
}

public void setAllocated(boolean allocated) {
    IsAllocated = allocated;
}
}
```

Here is my BindViewHolder of Adapter Class:

```
@Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(ViewHolder holder, int position) {

        list=Tlist.get(position);
        Log.v("vlist", String.valueOf(Tlist.get(position)));

        holder.tabletext.setText("Table");
        holder.status.setText(String.valueOf(list.isAllocated()));


    }
```

In values object, I am getting null values. Any help will be appreciated. Thank you in advance.

Comment: May we see your myRef definition?

Comment: Yes.  It's as below: myRef =database.getReference();






        myRef.child("Tables").addChildEventListener(new ChildEventListener() {

Answer (score 2):

Change your class variable it uses a case-sensitive you are using small char and your Firebase DB contains capital

change your class to:

```
public class Tables {
   int Capacity;
   String Customer;
   Boolean IsAllocated;
```

And use `ValueEventListener` to get all the records in single bunch

```
myRef.child("Tables").addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
    @Override
    public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
        try {
            for (DataSnapshot postSnapshot : dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {
                Tables values=dataSnapshot.getValue(Tables.class);
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {
    }
});
```

**Edit 1:** you can get value using map try below code

```
myRef.child("Tables").addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
    @Override
    public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
        try {
            for (DataSnapshot postSnapshot : dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {
                Map<String,String> map=(Map<String,String>)postSnapshot.getValue();
                String Customer=map.get("Customer");
                String IsAllocated= map.get("IsAllocated");
                String Capacity= map.get("Capacity");
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {
    }
});
```

Comment: I am so sorry.. I am newbie on stackoverflow too... It's by mistake.

Comment: @VaibhavJoshi can you again click on downvote button so it will remove downvote from my answer

Comment: Thanks for the resolution. But It resolved my problem partially. Now I am getting Capacity and Customer ID. but I am still getting null in IsAllocated. Please help.

Comment: @VaibhavJoshi change Boolean IsAllocated  to boolean IsAllocated (change class to primitive)

Comment: Yes. thanku for help. I really appreciate your help.thank you it worked perfectly for me.

Comment: @VaibhavJoshi most welcome one more thing can upvote my answer :P

Comment: Still there is a problem that datasnapshot is fine. but boolean value in object stays false as default even datasnapshot shows it as true. Here is Log.v for datasnapshot: '10-04 15:52:49.683 935-935/com.example.vaibhav.managerapp V/DS: {IsAllocated=true, Customer=-KpnRWVmEY7pG1oPe15z, Capacity=7}' and here is Log.v of IsAllocated : /10-04 15:52:49.683 935-935/com.example.vaibhav.managerapp V/isAl: false -KpnRWVmEY7pG1oPe15z 7 '

Comment: did you re-generate the getter and setter after changing Boolean to boolean?

Comment: why are you using `String.valueOf(values.getAllocated());` you can direcly print the `values.getAllocated()`

Comment: Still Not done with boolean values. They are still printing as default.

Comment: can you update your code on question so i can look into it

Comment: I need to use childEventListener only. I have updated my code in the question ,please have a look.

Comment: Thank you very much  for your Help but i solved it on my own. Renamed Json object **IsAllocated**  to **Allocated** and Local Variable **IsAllocated** to **Allocated**.  It solved my issue.